# How to combine SQL queries that returns more than a row without using `RIGHT JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to combine these two queries in SQLite3 without using `RIGHT JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN` if possible since the ide my course is using doesn't support them.

```
SELECT stations.name FROM stations, journey WHERE stations.id = journey.start_station_id
```

and

```
SELECT stations.name FROM stations,journey WHERE stations.id = journey.end_station_id
```

I want the first column to be the name of the start station and the second column to be the name of the end station. I found a few similar questions like mine but I still can't get the result I want. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the two names on the same column, it might be as easy as this:

```sql
SELECT stations.name
FROM stations, journey
WHERE stations.id = journey.end_station_id
  OR stations.id = journey.start_station_id
```

However, if you needs both on different columns, you could do something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    stations.name AS start_station_name,
    NULL as end_station_name
FROM stations
WHERE stations.id = journey.start_station_id
UNION
SELECT
    NULL AS start_station_name,
    stations.name as end_station_name
FROM stations
WHERE stations.id = journey.end_station_id
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't think a way to put the two rows on the same row. For example, the `GROUP BY` strategy failed.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    stations.name AS start_station_name,
    NULL as end_station_name,
    '-' AS result.equal_name
  FROM stations
  WHERE stations.id = journey.start_station_id
  UNION
  SELECT
    NULL AS start_station_name,
    stations.name as end_station_name,
    '-' AS result.equal_name
  FROM stations
  WHERE stations.id = journey.end_station_id
) AS result
GROUP BY result.equal_name
```

However, if you ask me, it's too much complexity for getting 2 names. There should be a more clever solution to get 2 names and identifying which one is the start station, which may include using Back-End programming languages.